# How do I create a duplicate of an object in C++ when working with classes and objects (Object Oriented Programming)

Tags: c++

> Create a friend function to duplicate a Shape object. The input parameter of this function will be
> a Shape object, and it will return the duplicated object. Use the compare function to show that
> the duplication is successful.

In this question, we were supposed to create a "Shape" class and add two private members: length and width (of the type double). Then, compute the area and parameter using those values. Also, we had to create two instances in the main and take user inputs for the values of length and width. All of this must be done using friend functions.

Could anyone please help with the duplication thing?

Okay, so I have compared both objects using the operator==() function. **Does it mean that creating a duplicate object is similar to creating a copy constructor?**

This is the code that I've written so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

// all functions need to be friend functions
class Shape {
    private:
        double length, width;
    public:
        Shape();
        Shape(double length, double width);
        friend double area(const Shape &sh3);
        friend double perimeter(const Shape &sh3);
        friend bool operator==(const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2);
        friend void Shape(const Shape &sh3, const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2);
};
Shape::Shape() {
    width = 0.0; length = 0.0;
}
Shape::Shape(double length, double width) {
    this->length = length; this->width = width;
}
double area(const Shape &sh3) { // friend fucntion to compute the area!
    return (sh3.width*sh3.length);
}
double perimeter(const Shape &sh3) { // friend fucntion to compute the perimeter!
    return (2*(sh3.length) + 2*(sh3.width));
}
bool operator==(const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2) { // friend function to compare the area of two objects!
    if (sh1.length == sh2.length && sh1.width == sh2.width) {
        cout << "Both shapes are equal\n";
        return true;
    }
}
//friend function to create a duplicate of the object:
void Shape(const Shape &sh3, const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2) { // calling the copy constructor
    class Shape sh4;
    if (operator==(sh1, sh2) == true) {
        sh4.length = sh3.length;
        sh4.width = sh4.width;
    }
}

int main () {
    double l, w; cout << "Enter the values for shape 1: "; cin >> l >> w;
    class Shape sh1(l, w); // onject 2
    double l1, w1; cout << "Enter the values for shape 2: "; cin >> l1 >> w1;
    class Shape sh2(l1, w1); // object 1
    class Shape sh3; // object3 using the preset values for l and w
    operator == (sh1, sh2); // to compare both objects

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in that `Shape` implementation that requires any help to be correctly copied. Observe the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Zero is discussed at the bottom of the linked page, but read the whole thing so you can understand how the Rule of Zero applies and what it avoids.

Comment: `sh4.width = sh4.width;` -- typo? Not a particularly useful statement.

Comment: It was supposed to be this: `sh4.width = sh3.width` -- typo!

Comment: @johnapplesead You might notice an "Edit" link at the bottom of your question. This is a not-so-secret way for you to correct your typos. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're almost there...  I'd just like to point out a couple of error in your code.

You can't call your function Shape(), there is a class called Shape, and you cannot declare a friend constructor.

```
class Shape {
    private:
        double length, width;
    public:
        Shape();
        Shape(double length, double width);
        friend double area(const Shape &sh3);
        friend double perimeter(const Shape &sh3);
        friend bool operator==(const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2);
  
        // friend void Shape(const Shape &sh3, const Shape &sh1, const Shape &sh2);
        // since we're going to copy Shapes We might as well define a copy contructor.
        Shape(const Shape& other) 
        { 
            length = other.length; 
            /* etc...*/ 
        }

        // One friend function that takes in a const ref and returns an object.
        friend Shape Duplicate(const Shape& other)
        {
            return other;  // calls the copy constructor
            
            // if no copy constructor, use another construtor to initialize object
            return Shape(other.length, other.width); 
        }
};

// ...

Shape a(1., 2.);
Shape b = Duplicate(a);   // spawning a new Shape

if (a == b)               // calling operator ==
   // do something
```